# remove space after writing a command when using \write

Tags: spacing, macros, write, white-space

I'm writing a macro to write commands to a file. These commands are supposed to be read when building my document.

The lines I use to write to the file is :

```
\newwrite\outtest
\immediate\openout\outtest=\jobname.ong
\immediate\write\outtest{\unexpanded{\ShowF{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}\wbgroup\getpagerefnumber{\the\value{line}}\wegroup \writepercent}%
```

It write things like this in the file `jobname.ong` :

```
\ShowF {1}{A}{AB}{ABI}{0}{\Trad {}{}{}{}}{5}%
\ShowF {1}{A}{AB}{ABO}{0}{\Trad {}{}{}{}}{5}%
\ShowF {1}{A}{AB}{ABR}{0}{\Trad {}{}{}{}}{5}%
```

I also need to use `\obeyspaces` to be uses in conjonction with a mono font.

For an unknown reason, my document fail to build with \obeyspaces but work fine without. I noticed that when I remove the blank lines in `jobname.ong`, my document compile fine :

```
\ShowF{1}{A}{AB}{ABI}{0}{\Trad{}{}{}{}}{5}%
\ShowF{1}{A}{AB}{ABO}{0}{\Trad{}{}{}{}}{5}%
\ShowF{1}{A}{AB}{ABR}{0}{\Trad{}{}{}{}}{5}%
```

**Do you know how to remove blank lines after a command in an output file ?**

**Do you know why `\obeyspaces` complain about these spaces ?**

Comment: please edit the question so people can run the example and see the issue, it is much harder to debug disconnected fragments.

Comment: if `\obeyspaces` is in force then in `\ShowF {1}{` the first argument of `\ShowF` is the active space not `{1}` is that your question?

Comment: I do not see any blank _lines_ do you mean avoid writing the space? perhaps `\immediate\write\outtest{\string\ShowF\unexpanded{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}\wbgroup\getpagerefnumber{\the\value{line}}\wegroup \writepercent}%`

Comment: Puting \string before the commands to write solve my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any blank lines do you mean avoid writing the space? perhaps

```
\immediate\write\outtest{\string\ShowF\unexpanded{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}\wbgroup\getpagerefnumber{\the\value{line}}\wegroup \writepercent}%
```